# VLOOKUP retrieving data under today's month and year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, excel-2010, vlookup

So my problem is that I cannot figure out how to use VLOOKUP to get data under today's month and year.

[image]

So as seen in the pic, I have data under every month of multiple years and I need to look up the data under today's month and year and input it into my designated cell.

I tried this formula among many others with the same concept but it didn't work:

```
=VLOOKUP(sheet2!C9;sheet2!B6:AD16;MATCH(TEXT(TODAY();"MMYYYY");Sheet2!E8:AD8;0);FALSE)
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: From the example in the picture above, it would be the "Value" field, since there are multiple rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `HLOOKUP` function is probably called for here:

```
=HLOOKUP(TEXT(TODAY(), "MMM-YY"), Sheet2!B6:AD16, 2, FALSE)
```

[image]

I'm also not sure about using semicolons in formulas like you've done. At any rate, `HLOOKUP` is more appropriate in this situation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I tried this and it keeps telling me that the value is unavailable. Does it maybe have to do with my date formats where for example my "MAR-21" in my sheet2 appears as "3/1/2021" in the formula bar

Comment: Yes, I suspect so. If the underlying value is "3/1/2021" and only the display is "Mar-21" then it won't work. You need the underlying value to be "Mar-21".